# Set specific line of multiline TextBox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, multiline

Hello I am new to C Sharp & Windows Forms.  I am unable to set the specific string of a multiline TextBox. I have tried below things so far.

`textBox1.Lines[1] = "welcome to stackOverflow";`

The above code does not give a compile time error but when I saw the result using Debug mode it was not expected.

Then i was also reading this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx) article but in this there is a new collection created by using `stream[]` constructor but still the same problem arises.

Answer (score 2):

It should give compiler error because you are trying to assign a `string` to `char` here:

```
textBox1.Text[1] = "welcome to stackOverflow";
```

`Text` property is of type `string`, when you use indexer on a `string` it gives you the `char` at that position. And also string is immutable so you can't really change a character at specific position without creating a new string.

You should set the `Text` directly like this:

```
textBox1.Text = "welcome to stackOverflow";
```

Or if you have more than one line in an array of string you should set the Lines property:

```
var lines = new [] { "foo", "bar" };
textBox1.Lines = lines;
```

Comment: thanks.But In my application i have to Replace multiline TextBox based on user option.so in this case i have to created new instances of string[] every time.Is there any other way?

Comment: OP seems tried to use `textBox1.Lines[1]` (msdn link confirm that), that would compile. And problem is that `Lines` simply returns **new** array (made from `Text`), changing items of that array wouldn't affect control. One have to always set new text (using either of properties) to control.

Comment: @Agyaat create a field `string[]` to store the lines. Change the array, set the Lines to that array. If you need to change number of lines recreate the array. If you need to update a specific line just set `lines[0] = "foo"`. Yes, you need to recreate the array when you want to add or remove lines, because arrays are fixed sized.

Comment: @SelmanGenç I don't get compile time error.Can you modify your previous answer with new answer as you described in comment.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any value that you set directly to textBox1.Lines will be effected to textBox1.

There is a solution to resolve your problem. I think it's best way.
You have to clone the current value of your textbox. Then you set new value on it. Finally, you set back to textbox.

```
var curValue = (string[])textBox1.Lines.Clone();
curValue[1] = "welcome to stackOverflow";

//Set back to textBox1
textBox1.Lines = curValue;
```