# Change Particular line of Multiline textbox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am unable to Change the specific string of a multiline TextBox.

suppose first line of multiline textbox is `"Hello"` & second line is `"Bye"`.But when i trying to change the value of second line like below.

`textBox1.Lines[1] = "Good bye";`

When I saw the result using Debug mode it was not "Good bye".

I also read this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx) article & this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000113/set-specific-line-of-multiline-textbox-in-c-sharp) question but can't get the desired answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As MSDN states (the link you provided):

> By default, the collection of lines is a read-only copy of the lines in the TextBox. 
>   To get a writable collection of lines, use code
>   similar to the following: textBox1.Lines = new string[] { "abcd" };

So, you have to "take" `Lines` collection, change it, and then return to `TextBox`. That can be achieved like this:

```
var lines = TextBox1.Lines;
lines[1] = "GoodBye";
TextBox1.Lines = lines;
```

Alternatively, you can replace text, like [Wolle suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44112503/6170890)

Answer (score 1):

First you need assign `textBox1.Lines` array in variable

```
string[] lines = textBox1.Lines;
```

Change Array Value

```
lines[1] = "Good bye";
```

Reassign array to text box

```
textBox1.Lines=lines;
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx)

> By default, the collection of lines is a read-only copy of the lines
>   in the TextBox. To get a writable collection of lines need to assign
>   new string array

Comment: Working with lines that way is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Working with `TextBox` lines via `Lines` property are **extremely** ineffective. Working with lines via `Text` property is a little better, but ineffective too.

Here the snippet, that allows you to replace one line inside `TextBox` without rewriting entire content:

```
public static bool ReplaceLine(TextBox box, int lineNumber, string text)
{
    int first = box.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineNumber);
    if (first < 0)
        return false;

    int last = box.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineNumber + 1);

    box.Select(first,
        last < 0 ? int.MaxValue : last - first - Environment.NewLine.Length);
    box.SelectedText = text;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: So, if working with `Lines` is ineffective, and with `Text` too, how do you work with `TextBox`? Is it possible at all? Do you need few extra gigs of RAM when there's two textboxes on form? What is both textboxes contain 1 kB of chars? IS IT EVEN POSSIBLE? Asking for a friend.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Look into my answer for a proof. As for working via `Lines` or `Text`, very high memory consumption (at least triple time when you're working via `Lines`) not the only drawback. There are others as well.

Comment: Looks like you didn't get the joke. I don't think there's need for your approach which unnecessary complicates code for, let's say, 10 lines. `Lines` iterates through char array that doesn't have any significant performance issues. I would like to see that triple time examples, especially with real life dara, not with 2 gigs of chars. And, after all, if texbox text is bottleneck in an application, one should give up on programming

Comment: I get it, but still sure that it is better to use right approach, well, almost always. And you don't need 2gb of chars to feel pain when updating `TextBox` via `Lines`, 20-30kb with lot of lines will be enough, resetting scroll position and flickering are only few to be named.

Comment: Ok, I agree with right approach, but on the other hand it would be wrong approach to put more than 10 lines in textbox. Textbox isn't meant to contain e-Books, so accessing it's lines by index seems like over-engineering.

Comment: I wrote text manipulation utility several years ago. It used TextBox.Lines as source of text data to work with. Also there is another TextBox to write results to. For several hundred rows of text it works without significant delay. However, first time when I needed to manipulate couple of thousands of rows I hit the wall. After replacing TextBox.Lines with simple string [] I could process this data in seconds. Now TextBoxes are used only to input the data from user (via Paste) and to show final result by setting Text property only.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace the text of second line like this:

```
    var lines = textBox.Text.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }).Where(x => x.Length > 0);
    textBox.Text = textBox.Text.Replace(lines.ElementAt(1), "Good bye");
```