# Multiline TextBox Move Last Line Up 1

Tags: c#

What i am trying to do is load in the contents of a multiline Text box to a method, which is done, that is easy enough, what i need to achieve is to move the last line of the textbox up by 1 place (or reverse the last line with the second last line)

**Code:**

```
        public void MoveLastLineUpOne(TextBox txtBox) {
            for (int i = 0; i < txtBox.Lines.Length; i++) {

            }
        }
```

The actual reversing of the last 2 lines is the part i am having issues with, i have never manipulated the Textbox values much in the past, i have tried to google the issue, from reading i think i need an `insert` (i think) at one point, i am more than likely over thinking this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not completely clear what you want. Just to swap order of 2 last lines in multiline TextBox? Why dont you just use helper variable and do swap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out [these solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44112453/change-particular-line-of-multiline-textbox-in-c-sharp/44112503#44112503)?

[Bear in mind especially that:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_TextBoxBase_Lines)

> By default, the collection of lines is a read-only copy of the lines in the TextBox. To get a writable collection of lines, use code similar to the following: textBox1.Lines = new string[] { "abcd" };

So something like the following should do the trick:

```
var originalLines = txtBox.Lines;
// Swap lines here
var temp = originalLines[originalLines.Length - 1];
originalLines[originalLines.Length - 1] = originalLines[originalLines.Length - 2];
originalLines[originalLines.Length - 2] = temp;
txtBox.Lines = originalLines;
```